# $variable = $url + static_page.php

Tags: php, curl

I would like to uplaod files using cURL but can't figure out how I can use $url array.
For example:

```
$urls = array("http://images.domain.com/",
              "http://flash.domain.com/",
              "http://other.domain.com/"
              );

      foreach ($urls as $url) {
```

I'm trying this but without success:

```
$upload = "$url ."upload/upload.php";
```

Any advice? :)
Thanks

Comment: `$upload = "{$url}upload/upload.php";`

Comment: or $upload = $url."upload/upload.php";

Comment: Remove the first quote: `$upload = $url."upload/upload.php";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take out the first quote for it to work

```
$urls = array("http://images.domain.com/",
              "http://flash.domain.com/",
              "http://other.domain.com/"
              );

    foreach ($urls as $url) {
         $upload = $url ."upload/upload.php";
}
```